# React, after querying the api, my page is overwritten without data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning react, and I've come across some strange behavior and I don't know how to solve it. When I send a query to the api with no data (I purposely do not handle exceptions before sending), the response returns fine and shows the expected exception. If I send a query with data, a response is returned, and it is immediately overwritten.
[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRPo.png)
I'm not sending any data here on purpose.
[bad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvx5X.png)
Here I send data (email, password) and the expected data is returned, but the page is overwritten. I don't understand why some new queries are created.

```
async function sendLogin(userLoginModel: LoginModelView) {
    let data = userLoginModel;

    await fetch(i.login.url, {
      method: i.login.methodType,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        var prom;
        if (response.ok) {
          prom = response.json() as Promise<ResultModel<UserModel>>;
          prom.then((result) => {
            setUser(result.data);
            handOverAlert(
              new AlertModel({
                message: result.message,
                isSuccess: result.isSuccess,
              })
            );
          });
        } else {
          prom = response.json() as Promise<ResultModel<boolean>>;
          prom.then((result) => {
            setUser(new UserModel());
            handOverAlert(
              new AlertModel({
                message: result.message,
                isSuccess: result.isSuccess,
              })
            );
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Calling the function using the context provider in Login

```
export default function Login() {

 const [login, setLogin] = useState<LoginModelView>({email:"", password:""});
 const { sendLogin } = useAuth()

 function handelChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
     const {name, value} = e.target;
     setLogin(prevlogin => ({
         ...prevlogin,
         [name]:value
     }))
 }

 function send() {
    sendLogin(login)   // HERE I am calling a function that calls the API
 
 }

 return (
     <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        
         <CssBaseline />
         <Paper 
             sx={{
                 marginTop: "3%",
                 display: 'flex',
                 flexDirection: 'column',
                 alignItems: 'center',
             }}
             >
             <Avatar 
                 sx={{
                     margin: "1%",
                     backgroundColor: "red",
                 }}>
                 <LockIcon />
             </Avatar>
             <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                 Přihlášení
             </Typography>
             <form>
             <FormControl 
                 sx={{
                     width:"100%",
                     marginTop: "1%"
                 }}>
                 <TextField
                     variant="outlined"
                     margin="normal"
                     required
                     fullWidth
                     id="email"
                     label="Email"
                     autoComplete="email"
                     autoFocus
                     name="email"
                     value={login.email}
                     onChange={e => handelChange(e)}
                 />
                 <TextField
                     variant="outlined"
                     margin="normal"
                     required
                     fullWidth
                     name="password"
                     label="Heslo"
                     type="password"
                     id="password"
                     autoComplete="current-password"
                     value={login.password}
                     onChange={e => handelChange(e)}
                 />

                 <Button
                     sx={{
                         margin: "1%"
                     }}
                     type="submit"
                     fullWidth
                     variant="contained"
                     color="primary"
                     onClick={send}
                     
                 >
                     Přihlásit
                 </Button>
                 <Grid container>
                     <Grid item xs>
                         <Link href="/ForgotPassword" variant="body2">
                             Zapomenuté heslo?
                         </Link>
                     </Grid>
                     <Grid item xs>
                         <Link href="/Register" variant="body2">
                             {"Nejste registrováni? Registrujte se"}
                         </Link>
                     </Grid>
                 </Grid>
             </FormControl>
             </form>
         </Paper>
     </Container>
 );
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: can you show where do you call that function ?

Comment: I think it better to see the code itself